# If $X, A_1$ are independent, and $X, A_2$ are independent, then are $X, A_1 \cdot A_2$ independent?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

There are RVs $A_1, ..., A_n$ and $X$.

$A_1$ and $X$ are independent,

$A_2$ and $X$ are independent,

...

$A_n$ and $X$ are independent.

Does it mean that $A_1 \cdot ... \cdot A_n$ and $X$ are also independent?

It seems that this can be proved by induction. But I can't figure out how to prove it for case $n = 2$.

Answer (score 2):

In two independent tosses of fair coin consider the event $A$ of the first toss being Head, the event $B$  of the second toss being Heads and the event $C$ of the two outcomes being both Heads or both Tails. Then $I_A$ is independent of $I_B$, $I_A$ is independent of $I_C$ but it is not true that $I_A$ is independent of $I_BI_C=I_{B \cap C}$